# How to correctly combine gzip and filestream object?

Tags: node.js, logging, stream

I am using [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) to log some messages. Because the message is big, I want to write in gzipped format.

The constructor of logger object has an argument of write stream. It works if I pass a file stream to it:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var out = require('fs').createWriteStream("test.log");
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      stream: out,
      json: false
    })
  ]
});
logger.info("test");
```

will produce `test.log` with

```
2013-09-12T07:53:14.795Z - info: test
```

I have read the document of [zlib](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib) which shows that:

> This provides bindings to Gzip/Gunzip, Deflate/Inflate, and DeflateRaw/InflateRaw classes. Each class takes the same options, and is a readable/writable Stream.

I tried to use `pipe` to combine `Gzip` and `fs` as follow:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var out = require('fs').createWriteStream("test.log");
var gzip = require('zlib').createGzip();
gzip.pipe(out, {end : true});
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      stream: gzip,
      json: false
    })
  ]
});
logger.info("test");
```

However, the `test.log` will be empty.

How to correctly combine gzip and filestream object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is generally OK. However `gzip` will not flush its output buffer until you've written quite a bit of data, so the file appears to be empty if you only write one line.

You can:

1) Write more data. (You need, iirc 16KB of compressed data).

2) Invoke `.flush()` on the gzip stream.